# Mouse click event not fireing

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have created a User Control that contains a button. The goal is to create a custom layout for my buttons that will be reused through the application:

```
public partial class Button : UserControl
{
    public Button()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 135, 190);
        button1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    [Description("Test text displayed in the textbox"), Category("Data")]
    public string TextSet
    {
        set { button1.Text = value; }
        get { return button1.Text; }
    }
}
```

When I add the Button user control to my application and create an event for MouseClick, the event does not fire. (Obviously each instance of the button will have a different event for mouse click)

Do I have to do something in my Button User Control code to forward the mouse click event?

Comment: What is button1? What is your exact code to set the event handler?

Comment: From the code I see Button AS(inheritance) UserControl but you are saying UserControl Has(composition) Button?? Also where you are trying to handle the click event inside UserControl or inside Form hosting UserControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subscribing to clicks of user control. But you are clicking a button which is located on your user control. Thus click event of user control is not fired. You can raise user control's click event manually when `button1` is clicked:

```
public partial class Button : UserControl
{
    public Button()
    {
        // note that you can use designer to set button1 look and subscribe to events
        InitializeComponent(); 
        button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 135, 190);
        button1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    // don't forget to subscribe button event to this handler
    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        OnMouseClick(e); // raise control's event
    }

    // ...
}
```

But it's better to inherit your button from `Button` class directly:

```
public partial class CustomButton : Button
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 135, 190);
        ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    [Description("Test text displayed in the textbox"), Category("Data")]
    public string TextSet
    {
        set { Text = value; }
        get { return Text; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
Error CS0060 Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Button' is less accessible than class 'CustomButton'

Comment: @Q-bertsuit make sure that you inherit from *System.Windows.Forms.Button* instead of your *Button* class

Comment: Oh wait, I got another error:

Error CS0115 'Button.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: @Q-bertsuit that means you don't have a virtual method with such signature :) What kind of actions you want to do on disposing of button?